# Django GenericForeignKey lookup for a given model

Tags: python, django

I use a voting app (django-ratings if that makes any difference) which uses django's GenericForeignKey, has a ForeignKey to User, and several other fields like date of latest change.

I'd like to get all the objects of one content type, that a single user voted for ordered by date of latest change. As far as I understand - all the info can be found in a single table (except the content_type which can be prefetched/cached). Unfortunately django still makes an extra query each time I request a content_object.

So the question is - how do I get all the votes on a given model, by a given user, with related objects and given ordering with minimum database hits?

Edit: Right now I'm using 2 queries - first selecting all the votes, getting all the objects I need, filtering by .filter(pk__in=obj_ids) and finally populating them to votes objects. But it seems that a [reverse generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) can help solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well right now we're using prefetch_related() from django 1.4 on a GenericRelation. It still uses 2 queries, but has a very intuitive interface.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out `select_related()`? That may help.

> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically "follow" foreign-key relationships, selecting that additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in (sometimes much) larger queries but means later use of foreign-key relationships won't require database queries.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 0):

From looking at [the models.py of the django-ratings app](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings/blob/master/djangoratings/models.py), I think you would have to do `user.votes.filter(content_type__model=Model._meta.module_name).order_by("date_changed")` (assuming the model you want to filter by is `Model`) to get all the `Vote` objects. For the related objects, loop through the queryset getting `content_object` on each item. IMHO, this would result in the least DB queries.

Comment: That seems to be n+1 queries where n is the number of objects a user voted for. That doesn't seem good to me.